# Анимированная тень на JS не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, анимация, frontend

Прописываю анимацию для объекта на странице. Менять размеры получается. Всё отлично. Чего не скажешь про тень.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".loading_circle-small")
        .animate({boxShadow: '30px 3px 6px 3px #0003'}, 500)
        .animate({boxShadow: '3px 3px 6px 3px #0703'}, 500)
        .animate({boxShadow: '3px 30px 6px 3px #0003'}, 500)
        .animate({boxShadow: '3px 3px 60px 3px #0003'}, 1000)
    }, 4000)
})
```

У меня не только тень исчезает там, где она должна быть, не только не работает анимация, а и выбивает такую ошибку в консоли: "Ошибка при парсинге значения «box-shadow».  Потерянное объявление." (К слову, выбивает ещё одну аналогичную ошибку: "Ошибка при парсинге значения «display».  Потерянное объявление.", где display у меня имеет значение flex).

Какие меры я уже пробовал предпринимать?

- писал значения с px и без px;
- менял количество параметров в значении;
- менял записи boxShadow, BoxShadow, box-shadow, брал в кавычки это свойство.

И всё безрезультатно.

Какие есть предложения, чтобы работали и тени? Интересует решение на JS.

Comment: `box-shadow` в кавычках надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> **Animation Properties and Values**
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality.

то есть

> Каждое анимируемое свойство должнo сводится к одному численному
>   значению

```css
.animated {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  animation: steps 2.5s;
}

@keyframes steps {
  0% {
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 30px 3px 6px 3px #0003;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 3px #0703;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 3px 30px 6px 3px #0003;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 60px 3px #0003;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">Test</div>
```